# Echo returns but value does not

Tags: php

```
if($_POST['login']) {
    if(isset($_POST['userName']) || isset($_POST['userPassword'])){
        echo 'logging failed';
        $this -> loginMsg = 'Login Failed!'; 
    }
}
```

hi all ive written a log in to stop the empty clicking of the login,
how ever im able to echo the loggin failed out but 
to generate it into the string it wont let me? i was wondering why.

Comment: you need a proper datastructure to hold the message. `$this->loginMsg` is not.

Comment: what does " generate it into the string" mean ?

Comment: are you doing this inside an object method? If not, then $this isn't going to work...

Answer (score 2):

If you're not in the context of an object (that is in a class), use a simple variable:

```
$loginMsg = 'Failed!';
```

Comment: if this isn't correct, i can't think of what is.

Comment: wow yes you are quite correct thank you its working now!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your checks are wrong. Should't it be:

```
if(!isset($_POST['userName']) || !isset($_POST['userPassword'])) {
   // log login failed error
   $loginMsg = 'Login Failed!';
}
```

Comment: If the checks were wrong, why would the echo message go through ?

Comment: no for some reason its isset instead of !isset

Comment: @karthikr: Not sure why anyone would throw an error if `userPassword` OR `userName` are set.

Comment: I agree, but but i felt the check was valid earlier. never mind. Just a thought

Comment: what is the correct way ?

Comment: @LearningPhPbasics: As I suggested in my answer you can use `!isset` or else use `empty` function calls as suggested by `web2students.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use empty in place of isset,

```
if($_POST['login']) {
    if(empty($_POST['userName']) || empty($_POST['userPassword'])){
        $loginMsg = 'Login Failed!'; 
    }
}
```

isset only checks it's set or not, empty also checks if value is at least 1 character long (in case of string) 
http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: how to stop people from loging on the site autmaticly as a login fail?

Comment: i am not getting your question, use session, if login is successful code will be like, `session_start();$_SESSION['user'] =  $_POST['userName'];` read sessions, email me web2students.com@gmail.com if futher questions. see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp